# Can't compile latest versions of Google API

Tags: visual-studio-2010, google-api-dotnet-client

I have tried to recompile the latest version of the GoggleAPI and I get the following errors.

I am using VS2010 Sp1. I have downloaded v1.8.1.

I need to be able to recompile so I can make changes to solve an issue I am having. I can step into the code but I cannot make any changes currently because I can't recompile.

Any ideas ... This is a followup to my previous post but the other post I think confused what I need help with.

I just need to be able to recompile. Can I not use VS2010 to recompile?

```
Build Log ------ Build started: Project: GoogleApis.Core, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------ 
C:\Work\BM Projects\GoogleAPI\v3 Source\Src\GoogleApis.Core\Apis\Http\ConfigurableMessageHandler.cs(161,60): error CS1003: Syntax error, '(' expected 
C:\Work\BM Projects\GoogleAPI\v3 Source\Src\GoogleApis.Core\Apis\Http\ConfigurableMessageHandler.cs(161,69): error CS1001: Identifier expected 
C:\Work\BM Projects\GoogleAPI\v3 Source\Src\GoogleApis.Core\Apis\Http\ConfigurableMessageHandler.cs(162,31): error CS1044: Cannot use more than one type in a for, using, fixed, or declaration statement 
C:\Work\BM Projects\GoogleAPI\v3 Source\Src\GoogleApis.Core\Apis\Http\ConfigurableMessageHandler.cs(162,48): error CS1002: ; expected 
C:\Work\BM Projects\GoogleAPI\v3 Source\Src\GoogleApis.Core\Apis\Http\ConfigurableMessageHandler.cs(175,32): error CS1519: Invalid token '(' in class, struct, or interface member declaration 
C:\Work\BM Projects\GoogleAPI\v3 Source\Src\GoogleApis.Core\Apis\Http\ConfigurableMessageHandler.cs(175,56): error CS1519: Invalid token ')' in class, struct, or interface member declaration 
C:\Work\BM Projects\GoogleAPI\v3 Source\Src\GoogleApis.Core\Apis\Http\ConfigurableMessageHandler.cs(178,13): error CS1519: Invalid token 'do' in class, struct, or interface member declaration 
C:\Work\BM Projects\GoogleAPI\v3 Source\Src\GoogleApis.Core\Apis\Http\ConfigurableMessageHandler.cs(180,63): error CS1519: Invalid token '(' in class, struct, or interface member declaration 
C:\Work\BM Projects\GoogleAPI\v3 Source\Src\GoogleApis.Core\Apis\Http\ConfigurableMessageHandler.cs(182,30): error CS1519: Invalid token '!=' in class, struct, or interface member declaration 
C:\Work\BM Projects\GoogleAPI\v3 Source\Src\GoogleApis.Core\Apis\Http\ConfigurableMessageHandler.cs(184,37): error CS1519: Invalid token '(' in class, struct, or interface member declaration 
C:\Work\BM Projects\GoogleAPI\v3 Source\Src\GoogleApis.Core\Apis\Http\ConfigurableMessageHandler.cs(185,30): error CS1519: Invalid token '=' in class, struct, or interface member declaration 
C:\Work\BM Projects\GoogleAPI\v3 Source\Src\GoogleApis.Core\Apis\Http\ConfigurableMessageHandler.cs(187,17): error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods C:\Work\BM Projects\GoogleAPI\v3 Source\Src\GoogleApis.Core\Apis\Http\ConfigurableMessageHandler.cs(219,84): error CS1518: Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct C:\Work\BM Projects\GoogleAPI\v3 Source\Src\GoogleApis.Core\Apis\Http\ConfigurableMessageHandler.cs(229,21): error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods 
C:\Work\BM Projects\GoogleAPI\v3 Source\Src\GoogleApis.Core\Apis\Http\ConfigurableMessageHandler.cs(240,17): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected 
C:\Work\BM Projects\GoogleAPI\v3 Source\Src\GoogleApis.Core\Apis\Http\BackOffHandler.cs(122,41): error CS1003: Syntax error, '(' expected 
C:\Work\BM Projects\GoogleAPI\v3 Source\Src\GoogleApis.Core\Apis\Http\BackOffHandler.cs(122,60): error CS1001: Identifier expected 
C:\Work\BM Projects\GoogleAPI\v3 Source\Src\GoogleApis.Core\Apis\Http\BackOffHandler.cs(122,96): error CS1002: ; expected 
C:\Work\BM Projects\GoogleAPI\v3 Source\Src\GoogleApis.Core\Apis\Http\BackOffHandler.cs(125,48): error CS1519: Invalid token '!=' in class, struct, or interface member declaration 
C:\Work\BM Projects\GoogleAPI\v3 Source\Src\GoogleApis.Core\Apis\Http\BackOffHandler.cs(125,59): error CS1520: Method must have a return type 
C:\Work\BM Projects\GoogleAPI\v3 Source\Src\GoogleApis.Core\Apis\Http\BackOffHandler.cs(125,103): error CS1001: Identifier expected 
C:\Work\BM Projects\GoogleAPI\v3 Source\Src\GoogleApis.Core\Apis\Http\BackOffHandler.cs(125,104): error CS1002: ; expected 
C:\Work\BM Projects\GoogleAPI\v3 Source\Src\GoogleApis.Core\Apis\Http\BackOffHandler.cs(127,60): error CS1001: Identifier expected 
C:\Work\BM Projects\GoogleAPI\v3 Source\Src\GoogleApis.Core\Apis\Http\BackOffHandler.cs(127,83): error CS1001: Identifier expected 
C:\Work\BM Projects\GoogleAPI\v3 Source\Src\GoogleApis.Core\Apis\Http\BackOffHandler.cs(127,107): error CS1001: Identifier expected 
C:\Work\BM Projects\GoogleAPI\v3 Source\Src\GoogleApis.Core\Apis\Http\BackOffHandler.cs(127,108): error CS1002: ; expected 
C:\Work\BM Projects\GoogleAPI\v3 Source\Src\GoogleApis.Core\Apis\Http\BackOffHandler.cs(128,21): error CS1519: Invalid token '.' in class, struct, or interface member declaration 
C:\Work\BM Projects\GoogleAPI\v3 Source\Src\GoogleApis.Core\Apis\Http\BackOffHandler.cs(128,22): error CS1520: Method must have a return type 
C:\Work\BM Projects\GoogleAPI\v3 Source\Src\GoogleApis.Core\Apis\Http\BackOffHandler.cs(128,37): error CS1031: Type expected 
C:\Work\BM Projects\GoogleAPI\v3 Source\Src\GoogleApis.Core\Apis\Http\BackOffHandler.cs(130,13): error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods 
C:\Work\BM Projects\GoogleAPI\v3 Source\Src\GoogleApis.Core\Apis\Http\BackOffHandler.cs(137,24): error CS1518: Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct 
C:\Work\BM Projects\GoogleAPI\v3 Source\Src\GoogleApis.Core\Apis\Http\BackOffHandler.cs(156,17): error CS1518: Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct 
C:\Work\BM Projects\GoogleAPI\v3 Source\Src\GoogleApis.Core\Apis\Http\BackOffHandler.cs(179,27): error CS1518: Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct 
C:\Work\BM Projects\GoogleAPI\v3 Source\Src\GoogleApis.Core\Apis\Http\BackOffHandler.cs(183,5): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected
...
Compile complete -- 3 errors, 0 warnings All packages listed in packages.config are already installed. ========== Build: 0 succeeded or up-to-date, 8 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Packages
`03/25/2014  05:40 PM    <DIR>          log4net.2.0.0
    03/25/2014  05:40 PM    <DIR>          Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.4.0.30506.0
    03/25/2014  05:40 PM    <DIR>          Microsoft.AspNet.Razor.2.0.30506.0
    03/25/2014  05:40 PM    <DIR>          Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.2.0.30506.0
    03/25/2014  05:40 PM    <DIR>          Microsoft.Bcl.1.0.19
    03/25/2014  05:40 PM    <DIR>          Microsoft.Bcl.Async.1.0.16
    03/25/2014  05:40 PM    <DIR>          Microsoft.Bcl.Build.1.0.10
    03/25/2014  05:40 PM    <DIR>          Microsoft.Net.Http.2.1.10
    03/25/2014  05:40 PM    <DIR>          Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.1.0.0.0
    03/25/2014  05:40 PM    <DIR>          Moq.4.0.10827
    03/25/2014  05:40 PM    <DIR>          Moq.4.1.1309.1617
    03/25/2014  05:40 PM    <DIR>          Newtonsoft.Json.5.0.8
    03/25/2014  05:40 PM    <DIR>          NUnit.2.6.2
    03/25/2014  05:40 PM    <DIR>          Zlib.Portable.1.9.2`

Comment: Did you use the solution which was checked-in to the repository? It should install all the required NuGet packages for you. Do you see a packages folder in your solution folder? All the errors looked really weird. It looks like we are missing something...

Comment: Yes. I edited the question to include the directory of the packages folder.

Comment: I didn't test it with VS2010. I'm working with VS2012. Do you install all latest updates for your VS2010? Can you try compile it with VS2012 Express?

Comment: I can now compile. You need VS 2012 Professional though because of the project types used in the solution.

Comment: Because it's PCL right? Can you publish your answer and marked this thread as closed? Thanks!

Comment: I believe that is correct. I did not investigate if there are other solutions in VS2010.